# Replacing mscorlib

Tags: c#, c++, unit-testing, clr, mscorlib

Can I replace mscorlib from GAC with another one built and possibly modified from the github source?

What are the instructions to do that?

I've tried to clone the repository and to rebuild it.

I've seen that I can compile a source with csc.exe, etc... but I'm having problems with the runtime linking part. If it is easier (I think so), I don't really need a standalone exe, but just adding a new specific unit test to verify a change would be enough.

I've tried to look at the tests currently implemented, but I can't find something that is checking one of mscorlib methods.

Finally, I am able to debug the C# native DLL as exposed in the reference source (without optimization) but I can't step into the C++ implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of mscorelib is included in the repo you've already rebuilt.

After any changes, you can code a new unit test starting from this [main entry](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/tests/src/readytorun/main.cs#L421) in the readytorun folder.

You'd be able to see the results next time you rebuild and run the tests.